# Get objects that are constrained by a specific Type in a List in C#

Tags: c#, class, generics, inheritance

If I have a list of objects of type `B<A>`, how can I get a list of objects that are constrained to be of type `B<D>`?

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
IList<B<A>> Bs = new ...

public class A
{

}

public class C : A
{
}

public class D : A
{
}

public sealed class B<T> where T : A
{
}
```

I want to obtain a list result that only contains objects of type `B<D>` from the original list of objects of type `B<A>`.

Something like:

```
var list = Bs.Where(o => o is constrained by D).ToList()
```

Comment: Use `OfType` method.

Comment: What do you mean *constrained by Generic D*? `D` is not generic. `B` is generic.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Fixed it.

Comment: Nothing is constrained by `D`. The constraint is that `T` must inherit from `A`.

Comment: D inherits from A, now my Bs list has Generics constrained by C and D. Both C and D inherit from A. I want only the Generic constrained by D from Bs list.

Comment: Please create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Then my answer should work. I am not sure what you mean by *it does not work*. You are a programmer so you should know that saying does not work is not very helpful. Please elaborate what does not work, do you get an error or do you get invalid result etc.

Comment: Your `IList<B<T>>` inside your question does not make much sense. You cannot  declare an open generic type, did you mean something like `IList<B<A>>`?

Comment: @CodingYoshi Did you even try your answer or just jumped and typed some answer here? It does not work means it does not give the write answer!

Comment: @FedericoDipuma You are right. I fixed it.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with sample inputs and expected outputs based on those sample inputs.

Comment: Do you understand that what you are presenting in your question does not even compile? As the others already said to you, please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you may even show us what you are trying to achieve using [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/)

Comment: You cannot have a B<D> in a list of B<A> anyway. The only way you could have both in a list is if you have a list of objects.

Comment: @MBakardzhiev Seems you are right. The original list can only contain objects.

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
yourList.OfType<D>();
```

To get all objects which are of type `D` in your list. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx) for more.

Comment: I want to a get a list that only contains B< D > objects.

Comment: then use OfType<B<D>>() (:

Comment: _How_ does it not work `Vahid`? Does it not compile? Throw an exception? Empty when you expected it not to be?